# Reopen "What is the next step up from shell scripts?" question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

[What paradigm to use when determining shell script vs a "proper" programming language?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/312680/52929)

I made a fairly significant edit to remove the "which language should I pick?" part of this question and focus on the core question.

Understanding how to decide when to move away from bash scripts is a question I think most programmers face and one where I believe there is a good, systematic approach towards understanding.

This got mod-clobbered right around when I edited it, for good reason, but this did not reflect the substantial edit I made.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this looks reopenable. Good edit, 10/10.

Answer (score 1):

I think you changed it from a "what language should I learn next" question into a "what project should I undertake next" question:

> I am trying to understand better what I can do as a next step instead
>   of creating a huge bash script program.

In the context of this question, "next step" is "what project should I work on next?" which is still off-topic.

This question needs a bit more work to focus on the conceptual idea of "what is the gap between shell scripting and 'real' programs filled by?" Even then, I am not sure it would be a good question anyway. I can do the same things a shell script does in a compiled language such as Java or C#, even if some tasks are more tedious to program in them (there is a tradeoff involved). The answer is basically "use Java or C# or a language like them." Or, for people who enjoy inflicting pain, use Perl.

No matter how I try to refactor the question in my head, this still ends up being off-topic or a "list of things" type question.

Comment: I think it's more... how do you determine when to move beyond shell scripting (or at least that's my intent behind the edit and what I believe is the core question).

Comment: I removed a line as I believe it didn't add to the question and did do what you are suggesting here.

Comment: @enderland your edits certainly do help, but it still has the same issues as I parse that final paragraph. I am not sure how to word this one, but it appears I may be in the minority with my opinion anyway.

Comment: I just made an edit to the title too, I always forget to edit them. :(